# Show duplicate grades of each department with department name and their grades

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, row-number, partition-by

I can show how many duplicate scores exist, but I can't show in which department.

```
select distinct *
  , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by f.depname order by f.stgrade) as ranked
from (
  SELECT COUNT(*) as repeatetive, DepName, stgrade
  FROM TBL_DEPARTMANTS
  CROSS JOIN TBL_GRADES
  group by stgrade, DepName
  having count(*) > 1
) as f
```

Comment: Please add some sample data with your expected output.

Comment: i want to show for example there are two 50 (score) in first department or four 60(score) in second one. but my code shows all duplicate scores for all departments.@mkRabbani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Do not use `CROSS JOIN` which yields multiple rows to return.
- You do not need a subquery, use window analytic function directly in the main query.
- Remove `partition by f.depname` part within the `row_number() over (..)` expression.

So, the following query suits well for your need :

```
select DepName, stgrade,
       row_number() over (order by g.stgrade,d.DepName) as ranked
  from TBL_DEPARTMANTS d
  left join TBL_GRADES g
    on g.DeptId = d.Id
 group by stgrade, DepName
having count(*) > 1;
```

assuming `TBL_GRADES` table has a column called `DeptId`( *Otherwise you'll need one more table to be added to this query with a `JOIN` statement* )

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c04263262427f893eb25d4d4f2b701bc)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Your sub query returning department and grade wise count where there are at lease 2 rows exist. Now, you can get distinct values for only Department and Grade from the Sub Query output as you add COUNT in the distinct list this will bring some duplicate data considering differences in COUNT. if you wants to get distinct list of Department and Grade, you can try this following script-

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       DepName, 
       stgrade
FROM TBL_DEPARTMANTS
     CROSS JOIN TBL_GRADES
GROUP BY DepName,stgrade             
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help ....

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), Department NVARCHAR(10), Score INT)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES 
('A', 10),
('A', 10),
('A', 20),
('A', 40),
('B', 10),
('B', 20),
('B', 20),
('C', 20)

;WITH DupLicateData
AS
(
  SELECT Id, Department,Score, COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY Department,Score ORDER BY Department,Score ASC) Rnk
  FROM @Table
)
SELECT Id, Department,Score
FROM DupLicateData
WHERE Rnk > 1
```